# read operator from file and perform operation C++

Tags: c++

In this problem I have to ask for a filename in which data will be read, and if 'def' is answered use the default file provided, and count the number of lines in the file.
Then read the data file one line at a time and calculate the value of w as follows:
-if w is 'add', calculate x+y
-if w is 'sub', calculate x-y
-if w is 'mult', calculate x*y
-if w is 'div', calculate x/y

and then print the results to the screen on line at a time.

example of data in the file:

> mult  4.25  4.56
>
> div  7.64  1.01
>
> div  6.51  2.46
>
> mult  8.90  6.16
>
> mult  7.40  8.53
>
> sub  3.05  7.15
>
> sub  9.51  6.16
>
> sub  5.79  1.60
>
> add  5.30  8.87
>
> sub  8.09  1.65

And my code: I have the first 3 parts work but the while loop for performing the operations isn't working. Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    ifstream input;
    string filename;
    cout<<"Enter the file name. Enter 'def' to use default file: ";
    cin>>filename;

    if(filename == "def"){
        input.open("M2-P2-data2Read.dat");
    }
    else{
        input.open(filename.c_str());   
    }

    int number_of_lines = 0;
    string line;

    while (getline(input, line))
        ++number_of_lines;
    cout << "Number of lines in file: " << number_of_lines;

    string w;
    double x, y;

    input >> w;

    while(input) {
    if(w == "add")
        double x, y;
        input >> x >> y;
        cout << "Solution: " << x+y << endl;
    if(w == "sub")
        double x, y;
        input >> x >> y;
        cout << "Solution: " << x-y << endl;
    if(w == "mult")
        double x, y;
        input >> x >> y;
        cout << "Solution: " << x*y << endl;
    if(w == "div")
        double x, y;
        input >> x >> y;
        cout << "Solution: " << x/y << endl;
    input >> w;
        
   }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you have expressed your intent to create a block of code after the `if` statements, the code is really not blocked. The lines

```
if(w == "add")
    double x, y;
    input >> x >> y;
    cout << "Solution: " << x+y << endl;
```

are equivalent to

```
if(w == "add")
{ 
    double x, y; // A declaration that does not have any impact on 
                 // the rest of the lines.
}
input >> x >> y; // These variables are the x and y that were declared
                 // before the while statement.
cout << "Solution: " << x+y << endl;
```

Now, if you transform the next `if` statement, you get

```
if(w == "sub")
{
    double x, y;
 }
 input >> x >> y;
 cout << "Solution: " << x-y << endl;
```

Your code attempts to read into `x` and `y` the second time without reading the operation, which fails since there is no number to read. After that, all read operations fail.

You need to block the statements after the `if`.

```
if(w == "add")
{
    input >> x >> y;
    cout << "Solution: " << x+y << endl;
}
```

You can simplify your code a bit by moving the lines that read `x` and `y` outside the `if` statements.

```
input >> x >> y;
if(w == "add")
{
    cout << "Solution: " << x+y << endl;
}

else if(w == "sub")  // Use else if instead of just if.
{
    cout << "Solution: " << x-y << endl;
}
```

etc.

Comment: I feel dumb for missing that. However, it still does not work after making the change

Comment: @TylerEmmerich, That's probably caused by the lines of code where you read the contents of the file using `getline` and never changing `input` to point to the start of the file.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are aiming for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::ifstream input;
    std::string   filename;
    std::cout << "Enter the file name. Enter 'def' to use default file: ";
    std::cin >> filename;

    if ( filename == "def" ) {
        input.open( "Sample.dat" );
    } else {
        input.open( filename.c_str() );
    }

    int number_of_lines = 0;
    std::string line;

    while ( getline( input, line ) ) {
        ++number_of_lines;
    }
    std::cout << "\nNumber of lines in file: " << number_of_lines << "\n\n";

    input.clear();
    input.seekg( 0, input.beg );    

    std::string w;
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;

    while ( input >> w >> x >> y ) {

        if ( w == "add" ) {
            std::cout << "Solution: " << x + y << std::endl;
        }

        if ( w == "sub" ) {
            std::cout << "Solution: " << x - y << std::endl;
        }

        if ( w == "mult" ) {
            std::cout << "Solution: " << x * y << std::endl;
        }

        if ( w == "div" ) {
            // Should test for denominator = 0
            std::cout << "Solution: " << x / y << std::endl;
        }

    }


    std::cout << "\nPress any key and enter to quit." << std::endl;
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;

    return 0;
}
```